# Read files outside Tomcat's directory

Tags: java, linux, tomcat8

In a Linux server, my java app is installed on:

*/opt/apache-tomcat8/webapps/myApp/*

Under the previous directory, I can read/write files easily, however I need to check the existance of some images that are located in a total different directory:

*/home/mywebsite/public_html/image/catalog/mainImages/*

and I haven't been able to do so. I've even tried giving 777 permissions to the *mainImages* folder, but Tomcat it's still not able to read from that directory.

I don't think my java code is relevant here, but just in case (I've deleted unnecesary extra code):

```
            filePath = prefix + listImagesArr[i][1];
            File f = new File(filePath);
            if(f.exists()){
                System.out.println("Directory exists!!");
                if (f.isFile()) {
                    //do nothing
                    System.out.println("File exists");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Directory doesn't exist");
            }
```

I always get "Directory doesn't exist", but trust me, the directory is there.

Is this related with linux users/groups?

Any help will be really appreciated!!

**UPDATE!!**

After some research, I'm stuck here.

I've found a way to check permissions for a user/folder.

All the folders of this path have a user & owner called "*itlogiccom*"
The linux Tomcat's user is called "*tomcat8*"

I've added *tomcat8* to the *itlogiccom* group:

```
lid -g itlogiccom
itlogiccom(uid=512)
tomcat8(uid=490)
```

So now, tomcat8 should be able to read directories & files where itlogiccom is the owner and have the necesary permissions.

Using *sudo* and *test* I can check if the user *tomcat8* is able to read from the specified directory. When the read is successful, the output is "0", if not, it's any other number. In the next code you'll see that the first 4 cases are successful, however, when I try to read from the *home* directory, the read is not successful (output is 1):

```
[/home/mywebsite/public_html/image/catalog]# sudo -u tomcat8 test -r ./mainImages/ZKTN3S.jpg; echo $?
0
[/home/mywebsite/public_html/image]# sudo -u tomcat8 test -r ./catalog/mainImages/ZKTN3S.jpg; echo $?
0
[/home/mywebsite/public_html]# sudo -u tomcat8 test -r ./image/catalog/mainImages/ZKTN3S.jpg; echo $?
0
[/home/mywebsite]# sudo -u tomcat8 test -r ./public_html/image/catalog/mainImages/ZKTN3S.jpg; echo $?
0
[/home]# sudo -u tomcat8 test -r ./mywebsite/public_html/image/catalog/mainImages/ZKTN3S.jpg; echo $?
1
```

mywebsite and public_html have the same group/owner, and the same permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 40 itlogiccom itlogiccom 4096 Feb  5 14:21 mywebsite/
drwxr-xr-x+ 12 itlogiccom itlogiccom 4096 Feb  5 16:13 public_html/
```

So this is why I just don't understand why I'm not able to read from the "home" directory.

By the way, if I perform the same test, using the "itlogiccom" user instead, the the read is successful:

```
[/home]# sudo -u itlogiccom test -r ./mywebsite/public_html/image/catalog/mainImages/ZKTN3S.jpg; echo $?
0
```

I don't understand why this behavior is happening. All I need is that the user "tomcat8" can read files from this path:

*/home/mywebsite/public_html/image/catalog/mainImages/*

Any help will be really appreciated!!

Just to be clear enough, if I try to read from:

*/home/mywebsite/* (and every folder down this path), the read is successful.

but when I read from:

*/home/*

The read is not successful

Comment: Have you tried printing `filePath`? Does it contain what's expected?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it contains exactly what is expected

Comment: Does "other" have execute permission on _all directories leading up to `mainImages`_?

Comment: The linux user that uses Tomcat is tomcat8, and no, it doesn't have permission on all directories leading up to the `mainImages` folder

Comment: What linux distribution are you using? How did you install Tomcat, with the help of a package manager? Please, verify if you have SELinux enabled - `selinuxenabled; echo $?`. If that is the case, perhaps it can be the cause of the problem because you are trying to access to a non standard Tomcat directory.

Comment: @jccampanero Linux version: CentOS release 6.10 (Final). About tomcat, it's a regular, standard Tomcat installation (not the cPanel's version). When I run ´selinuxenabled; echo $?´ the output is 1. However, using sudo and test, I'm just testing the ´tomcat8´ user.

Comment: Hi @Sergio. Thank you for the feedback. Yes, the permission issue is strange indeed, I mean, why you are able to `test` the file with an user and not with the other when you run  the `test` command from the `home` directory. In any way, pay attention to the actual application problem, not to the permission `tests. The permissions look fine. If you are using CentOS with SELinux enabled it can be very likely the cause of the problem. You can verify it with the help of the `ausearch` utility: try to access your image and then use the tool to look for permission denial. See next comment

Comment: Something like: `ausearch -m AVC -ts recent | grep denied | tail` or `ausearch -m AVC --start 07/02/2021 09:00:00 | grep denied | tail`. The start date format depends on the locale of the machine, change it as appropriate. Please, see this related Red Hat [article](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2191331). Please, can you try and see if the permission denial is there?

Comment: @jccampanero  thank you for your suggestions. I'll try them out and let you know whta the result is

Comment: Output of `ls -ld /home`?

Comment: @lainatnavi sorry for my late reply. I've got a flu and couldn't connect here before. Anyway, the output is: `drwxr-x--x+ 25 root root 4096 Feb  9 14:15 /home/` BTW, tomcat8 is also a member of "root" group

Comment: @jccampanero the ausearch output is `<no matches>` (in both cases)

Comment: Sorry to hear that you were ill, I am happy to see that you feel better now. I am sorry, I was sure that the problem was this, I faced a similar issue some time ago. Did you test with different dates?

Comment: @jccampanero it wasn't that, but it was a similar thing that caused this. I've just figure it out and posted an answer. I created a new directory and realized that I was able to read from there, so I knew that something else was preventing the user tomcat8 from reading the /home directory. It turned out to be some ACL's

Comment: That is great @Sergio, I am happy to hear that you were able to find a solution. Yes, you are right, the `+` sign in your directory permissions `drwxr-x--x+` indicates that there are some ACLs applied to it. I am happy to hear that you realized the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if many of the comments here were very helpful, the main problem in this case was related to some ACL's (Access Control Lists) that were preventing the user "tomcat8" from reading in the directories I was trying to read.

These rules were deleted so now everything works like a charm.

Comment: how did you delete the ACL or what steps did you perform? I am facing same issue.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, my computer battery died. I didn't do this personally, some guy from tech support did it, but I guess you can google it. An extra asterisk was shown when I listed these directories, but after deleting these ACL's, the asterisks were removed.

Answer (score 0):

2 things you can do here first verify permission it must be like rwrwrw and test by giving full path. I fell you are using mac system. To get full path copy folder and past into terminal. You will see full path of your file folder. And use that path.

Comment: Trying reading the full path doesn't work. That's why I'm trying to figure out where the problem is. I'm looking at the very full path, there's no shorcuts or anything like that. About the permissions, it works with the permissions defined now (755), as you can see in the code (inside the update section)

Answer (score 0):

**Hey bro,**

I'm not familiar with tomcat standalone because I only develop SpringBoot apps, but before a few days I struggled with the same problems like you.

1. At beginning there was a permission error, most important is that **you own the folder where the .jar is running** and **run the .jar with the user that owns the directory**. Or you just use sudo or execute as root, this will work definitely.
2. Next step is to announce your external directory to your Java app. You can do it like this:

   ```
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

   @Configuration
   @PropertySource({ "classpath:server.properties" })
   public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

       @Value("${server.home}")
       private String serverHome;

       @Value("${server.images}")
       private String serverImages;

       @Override
       public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

           String file = "file:";

           // Add custom locations from server outside of .jar file.
           registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(file + 
               this.serverHome).setCachePeriod(0);
           registry.addResourceHandler("/server-images/**").addResourceLocations(file 
               + this.serverImages).setCachePeriod(0);
        }

   }
   ```

- I added two resource location:

  - `"/resources/**"` **inside** the .jar
  - `"/server-images/**"` **outside** the .jar on the server
- You might wonder about these @Value(...) Strings, they are:

  ```
   server.home = /home/neo/foodguy/
   server.images = /home/neo/foodguy/images/
  ```

  - Replace `"neo"` with your user
  - Create a folder `"images"` on `/home/neo/foodguy/`

As you can see the folder's name on server is different from the resource handler's name. You can set them equal if you like. This line `String file = "file:";` is very important and the code won't work without.

4. If you have security foo enabled you must allow every request if it's for publicity. I use Keycloak as role-based user-management software. Maybe it's a little different on your machine because you may not use Keycloak, but surely you have a security-configruation class where you can allow and deny URLs. I did this:

   ```
      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

          super.configure(http);

          !! http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/server-images/**").permitAll(); !!

          http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/welcome-page").permitAll();
          http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/memberarea/**").hasRole("member");
          http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/adminarea/**").hasRole("admin");
          ...........
       }
   ```
5. You can do now this at the front-end:

   ```
       <img src="/server-images/event.webp" class="..." alt="...">
   ```

- The image will be loaded from `"/home/neo/foodguy/images/event.webp"` via the resource handler `"/server-images/**"` you created earlier.

A bonbon at least: My customer want's to upload flyer for holidays like Xmas, Halloween, etc. and I need to manage user uploads by my customer. I build a upload form in the back-office:

```
<!--/* th:action adds automatically csrf token */-->
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/login/admin/upload}" class="py-3 mt-4">

    <!--/* Form heading */-->
    <div class="row mb-1">
        <div class="col text-left">
            <h3 class="d-inline font-weight-bold" th:text="#{admin.eventflyer.title}"> 
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- /* Upload form */ -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileInputEventFlyer">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-grow bg-color-green text-white">
    </div>
</form>
```

Notice the `"multipart"` datatype. In the back-end I do this to handle the upload:

```
@Controller
@PropertySource({ "classpath:server.properties" })
public class MemberController {

    @Value( "${server.images}" )
    private String serverImages;

    @PostMapping("/login/admin/upload")
    @PreAuthorize(Roles.HAS_ADMIN)
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        
        File pathToEventFlyerWEBP = new File(this.serverImages + "event.webp");
        File pathToEventFlyerPNG = new File(this.serverImages + "event.png");
        
        try {
            file.transferTo(pathToEventFlyerWEBP);
            file.transferTo(pathToEventFlyerPNG);
        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException exc) {
            Logbot.exception(this.getClass(), new Throwable(), exc);
        }
            
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help you to manage up- and downloads outside the Java .jar on your server.

Don't hesitate to contact me if you have further questions.

---

**Kind regards** 
**Kevin**

Comment: Remember: If you run .jar within Tomcat, I mean a non-SpringBoot app, than the base-directory is the Tomcat JVM. Not the directory where you put the .jar as you might think.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I don't need to read files outside my jar file. I'm actually not using a jar file but a simple java class. What I need is to be able to read outside Tomcat's directory. As the post begins, Tomcat is installed in `/opt/apache-tomcat8/etc..` and I need to check the existance of some files in a different directory `/home/mywebsite/public_html/etc...` Also, I don't need to "serve" this images or display them anywhere, I just need to check if they exist. The problem is that Tomcat cannot read from the directory where the images are located.

Comment: OK, then add a resource handler, specify the directory on the server and mapp it. It's the first box of code in my answer. Don't forget: /resources/** is already mapped by default, it's the same with a custom resource handler: write the name of the folder inside the handler. Example: "/resources/static/css/...." you just write "/static/css/...". The entry point of the resource handler is the base directory and you can read and write to the subfolders directly.

Comment: thank you, however, I need to read from `/home/mywebsite/public_html/etc. etc.` because that's where the images are. Being able to read from `/resources/and_some_other_folder` doesn't solve my needs.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Try recursively setting permissions on the public_html folders to give yourself access to the folder and all it’s containing folders.

```
 chmod -R 755 /home/mywebsite
```

The chmod sets permissions to owner write, group read and execute, all read and execute.

If you don’t want to use -R (because you have other things in the directories you don’t want to share) then do this commands on each individual directory within the full path to your images.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sadly, I can't change the owner of /home/ or /mywebsite/ because the application running there (it's OpenCart, by the way) will crash. Also, some other website that uses Wordpress won't run either.

Comment: Edited to only change permissions, not change owner.